# How to get total count for given time period in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

Background: We have an api which different api users are calling from different companies. We are logging every request in `DataDog`. From DD, I am fetching those logs every minute, get the required data i.e. `apiUserKey`, `companyName`, `dateAccessed`, `apiVersion` etc. I am logging each of this request in a DynamoDB table called `EpgApiStatistics` as shown in the image.

I can paginate through the list but I also need to maintain the total count for each api user and also the total count for each company(channel). For this purpose I have created two separate tables where I have the `apiUserkey` as partition key and `channelId` as parition key and then increment the total count.

My question is how can I calculate total count for a given time period or range of time. Let's say we want to see total api calls by a user from 10th to 17th November or month etc?

[image: Main table with api calls details]
[image: Total api calls count for each api user]
[image: Total api calls count for each company]

I have read about GSI (global secondary index) but I am confused how can I use them in my current setup. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the statistic table's `PartitionKey` and `SortKey`?

Comment: @fedonev `ParitionKey` for the Statistics table is the first one on the list i.e. `ApiUserKey` and `SortKey` is just a random number (second from the left) to make the composite key unique.

Comment: Helpful, thanks.  Another question, this one about access patterns for the date range queries.  Are the date range queries primarily run as _bulk jobs_ (say daily or hourly _for all ApiUserKeys_ to populate the access counts table)?  Or do clients make _ad hoc requests_ for date range access counts _for one ApiUserKey_ on demand?  Or do both patterns apply?

Comment: Further clarification: When we save the data in the `Statistics` table, I push the same data to `AWS SQS` queue where a separate job runs which calculates the total and saves it in the two total related tables. *Now answer to your question*: No the date range queries are NOT in bulk, they are only available in the admin interface, which we will only execute/fetch once an admins goes to a company page and wants to see the total calls for an api user or total calls for a company in the specified date range.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Query individual ApiUserKey by date range

Repurpose the `SortKey` column to include the log's timestamp:

`SortKey` for each log entry becomes: `Log#<Timestamp>` or `Log#<Date>#<Random>`

We can now query by day, month, and year date range for an individual ApiKey
`ApiUserKey=<APIKey> and starts_with(SortKey, Log#2021-11)`

For date range queries such as weeks or arbitrary from-to dates, you have to combine a query (overfetch based on `>` or `<` or `starts_with`) with a  [filter expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Query.FilterExpression).

#### Query all api keys for a certain date range

To get logs in a range for *all ApiKeys*, add a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.OnlineOps.html), where you reverse the above keys.  The timestamp becomes the GSI Partition Key, and the ApiKey the GSI Sort Key.

#### Query channels by date range

Same pattern.  Add a second GSI, with the channel as GSI PK and the timestamp as GSI SK.  You use this second index to query by channel with >, < or = on the timestamps.

Important to note:  dynamodb **makes a copy** of all the indexed line items for each added index.

Comment: @feonev thanks for the detailed answer. We are getting approximately a million requests per month, let's say an admin wants to see how many calls were made by an API user in one month e.g. from 2021-10-17 - 2021-11-17. Then don't you think, it will be an expensive query to run each time an admins tries to see the result? What does this mean "dynamodb makes a copy of all the indexed line items for each added index."? Thanks

Comment: Re: efficiency:  My answer addressed only the OP, which was how to `query`, rather than `scan`  the log data for date ranges.   Separately, given your use case, it seems good to cache your date query results.  In fact, storing pre-calculated results is a [common dynamo design pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/creating-a-single-table-design-with-amazon-dynamodb/).  One approach would be to pre-calc daily results.   You could (perhaps should) get rid of your 2nd table and cache log results in your stats table.  PK is `ApiUserKey`, SK is, say `Sum#Daily#2021-11-17`.

Comment: Re: adding an index copies the data:  I mean exactly that.  Dynamo indexes work by [literally copying the indexed data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) behind the scenes.

Comment: All good questions!   The hardest part of learning dynamo is unlearning many of the patterns and practices from relational dbs.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, I am gonna look at that link "common dynamo design pattern". I will try your suggestions and see where it goes. I am marking you answer as accepted. If I have further questions, will ask them here.